# Parsing multiple files using logstash

Tags: logstash

Is it possible to make logstash (using single config file) to parse multiple input files (either parallely or one by one) and give multiple outputs (one for each input file)? "Parsing each input file is NOT dependant on each other."

Ultimately, I don't want to run different logstash instance to process each input file.

Thanks much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating different "type" for each file input and using if else condition in filter/output plugin works fine.

```
file {
    type => "one"
    ...
}
file {
    type => "two"
    ...
}
```